# Find Magento 2 API Username to use in Paypal

Tags: magento2, api, paypal, payment

I have set up my Magento E-commerce website. I have a Paypal Business account but in the moment when configuring Paypal it says: 
[image: ThirdParty Permissions Username]

Where is Magento 2 can I find or make this username? All I have been able to find are the API settings Paypal gives, which is fine but now I need Paypal to accept my website.

Answer (score 6):

You'll go into the Profile of the account and request the API Signature that you'll copy and paste into Magento 2.

From your PayPal business steps: 
**Tools > All Tools > API Credentials**, you'll select "Manage API credentials" under NVP/SOAP API integration (Classic)

Answer (score -3):

You can configure Paypal for magento2 by login to magento admin Then select

> Stores => configuration => Sales => Payment Methods

But before configuring on magento admin, you need to login to your paypal account to request **API credentials**

You can found very details steps on my blog

http://tvivu.com/magento2-paypal-configuration/

Comment: link is broken and navigating back from it does not work...